# How to reload .com.apple.iokit.graphics underscan without restarting?

Tags: macos, graphics, terminal, monitor

I'm looking into making a script that automatically turns off underscan when my `Plex Home Theater.app` is running.

So far I have found the file containing the setting at `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics`.

Then I tried changing the underscan value in the settings file with `PlistBuddy`:

```
# underscan 100%
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /private/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics -c 'Set "IOService\:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2/AppleIntelFramebuffer@2/display0/AppleDisplay-3dcb-e51:pscn" 8800'

# underscan off
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy /private/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics -c 'Set "IOService\:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2/AppleIntelFramebuffer@2/display0/AppleDisplay-3dcb-e51:pscn" 10000'
```

But changing the file alone didn't apply the new underscan setting, so I tried restarting to see if the setting would take effect – **it did**.

So does anyone know how to change the underscan setting without restarting?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the plist settings content to enable/disable/adjust underscan?

Comment: @Gusman, I added the commands to change the setting to my question. Basically, you have to look for the `pscn` entry in `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics`. The display ID depends on the display, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot reitermarkus